# Why is the navigation method not accepting the parameter?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a UI for windows phone; I have written event handlers to navigate between pages:

```
private void Settings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Settings));
        }
```

They all function correctly when debugging except for one, despite having used the same form: creating the click method for the specified button and running the navigate method, passing the desired page as parameter.

Comment: what is the difference to your other methods?

Comment: Only difference is the button to which the event handler is assigned and the page navigated to (which is settings in the code above).

Comment: @jacka92 Maybe you have another class named Settings and when navigating Frame thinks about it but not about the page? Try to fix namespaces usage if that is the reason.